Does oral Torah contradict the Torah on cross-dressing?
Deuteronomy 22:5 appears to say that no one is allowed to wear the other gender’s clothes.  However the Talmud and Rashi say that this only applies if it is part of some kind of scheme to engage in unchastity.  This seems unnecessary given that that’s banned in general.  Cross-dressing is also explicitly allowed on Purim.  But how then can the second part of the verse be true (For everyone doing these things is an abomination to the LORD your God)?  How could God say that something is an abomination to Him but then later explicitly tell people that they are allowed to do it?

If I understand their reading correctly, it's not inherently an abomination, but it's forbidden when it can lead to an abomination.

What does this have to do with missionary arguments? And why should we care?

Does oral Torah contradict the Torah...? No. The Oral Torah is the definitive interpretation of the Written Torah. It might contradict a shallow reading, but that's why the oral tradition exists.

The interpretation of Rabbis does not contradict the verse. There can be situations when no other dress is available for a man to cover himself and one has to do it out of modesty. Alternatively, during the cossack attacks some Jews used female dress to conceal themselves and save their lives. Certainly, the Torah does not forbid such actions as one has to choose life as it says in Devarim 30:19. Therefore, the Rabbis in Gemara Nazir 59a and Sifrei Devarim 226 treat the general prohibition on cross-dressing for both men and women (כְּלָל) in the first part of the verse to be limited by a specification abomination (פְּרָט) used in the second part of the verse. This is an application of Rule 4 of the 13 principles of Rabbi Yishmael.
Alternatively, as Fred points in the comment, the word כי used in the verse, should not be translated as for/because, due to obvious problems which were noted at the beginning. Rather, one should translate this word as if/when, to inform about cases when the prohibition applies, as stated in Rosh Hashanah 3a,

as Reish Lakish said: The word ki is used in the Bible in four senses: If, perhaps, but, and because.


Note that this informs rather than contradicts the literal meaning of the verse (see Rosh HaShana 3a, "דאמר ריש לקיש כי משמש בד' לשונות אי דילמא אלא דהא").

@Fred So how should it be translated then?

@wmasse Replace "for" in the second half of the verse with "if" or "when".
